# "even" in "Now can you even come up with a decent plan"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, understanding, word-stress

I've encountered an `even` use when reading an article.

I don't know what does it stand for in this sentence.

I wonder that is `even` in the sentence below an adverb, an adjective or a verb? And it provides a stress or anything?

```
Now can you even come up with a decent plan.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [even](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/even_1) in this sense provides emphasis.

> When emphasizing verbs, **even** comes before an ordinary verb
>
> (Macmillan Dictionary)

It's not an adjective because it doesn't modify a noun. It's an adjective when it means "flat and smooth"

> prepare the site, then lay an even bed of mortar
>
> (Oxford Dictionary)

Comment: But in `Now can you even come up with a decent plan` sentence, `even` comes after `subject` which comes after a `modal`. A verb must be after subject in this case. Must not it? If so, even should be used as a verb.

Comment: @efkan it comes before the verb. In your example, the verb is "come".

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @efkan Ohh nooo, why would you say sorry? I'm glad that I can help you. :)